How to get a11y-related attributes?
Now I'm on a AT-tool development, I want to control the app by using voice to accomplish some actions. I searched the wkwebview's documentation and I didnt find a way to get the element of the app.
I wrote a script to get the element and I use it to test.
AXUIElementRef appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(app.processIdentifier);
    if (appRef == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to get AXUIElementRef for app: %@", app.localizedName);
        return;
    }
    
    CFArrayRef windows = NULL;
    AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&windows);

I tried to set the attribute "AXManualAccessibility' like electron but failed.
